# mvc routing for pagination and dates

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-routing

I have a routing system that can pass either no date or date with page number.

```
routes.MapRoute(
            name: "ArticlesArchiveFilter",
            url: "Article/Archive/{searchDate}/{pageNumber}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Article", action = "Archive", searchDate = UrlParameter.Optional, pageNumber = "" }
        );

        routes.MapRoute(
           name: "ArticlesArchiveBasic",
           url: "Article/Archive/{pageNumber}",
           defaults: new { controller = "Article", action = "Archive", pageNumber = "" }
       );
```

My problem is that when passing a url the url route with datetime and page number works but not without the datetime as the page number will always default to 1.

my controller looks like this...

```
 public ActionResult Archive(DateTime? searchDate, int pageNumber = 1)
    {
        ArticleListViewModel model = new ArticleListViewModel();
        model = new ArticlePageManager().Filter(searchDate, pageNumber: pageNumber).MapToList();

        return View(model);
    }
```

Anyone know how I can sort this out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing your route to this.

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "ArticlesArchiveFilter",
    url: "Article/Archive/{pageNumber}/{searchDate}",
    defaults: new { controller = "Article", action = "Archive", searchDate = UrlParameter.Optional, pageNumber = "" }
);
```

Comment: Thanks. This worked but the reason my other one was not working because it conflicted with the default mvc route. But this one is much simpler.